# Nodetool load and own stats

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

We are running 2 nodes in a cluster - replication factor 1.
After writing a burst of data, we see the following via node tool status.

- Node 1 - load 22G (owns 48.2)
- Node 2 - load 17G (owns 51.8)

As the payload size per record is exactly equal - what could lead to a node showing higher load despite lower ownership?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Did you expect a different distribution of data?

Comment: With payload size per record being equal - what would a higher load with lower ownership indicate?when can this happen

Comment: Can you perhaps add that comment to the question? That would make it a lot more precise

Answer (score 2):

Nodetool status uses the Owns column to indicate the effective percentage of the token range owned by the nodes. While GB is Size of your records

Answer (score 1):

Dont see anything wrong here. Your data is almost evenly distributed around your two nodes which is exactly what you want for perfekt performance.